# Can I define a generic that can take several possible value types? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, generics

Is there any way to define a Generic in VB.NET which will accept only Singles or Doubles?

I tried the following things, based on what I've found online, but none compile:

```
Dim target As Nullable(Of {Single, Double})  
Dim target As Nullable(Of T As {Single, Double})
Dim target As Nullable(Of T {Single, Double})
Dim target As Nullable(Of Single, Double)  
Dim target As Nullable(Of T As Single, Double)
```

I want to specify that `target` can either be a `Single?` or a `Double?` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Public Class NullableFloat(Of T As {Double, Single})` is the right syntax, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y2755) under constraints.

However, this statement specifies that the generic type `T` must implement both `Double` and `Single`, not either. Since .Net primitives are sealed and there is no inheritance relationship between `Double` and `Single` there is no way that `T` could ever satisfy both constraints.

Since no .Net type can be both a `Double` and a `Single` you could make some complex type called `NullableFloat` with one `Value` property of `Double` type but with setters that take `Double` or `Single` but, why not just use `Nullable(Of Double)`.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of base Integral and Numeric types is a real pain; I know they are looking at adding that for a future version as per connect. I hadn't thought of using multiple function calls as you suggest, ... guess that might be the best possible idea. Was just hoping for some way not to have to write 2, 3, or more functions all with the same signature, save for the generic param.

Comment: had a rethink and hope my new answer makes sense.

Comment: Um, no. `Of T As {Double, Single}` would describe a `T` that is **BOTH** a `Double` and a `Single` SIMULTANEOUSLY -- which is of course impossible. The "multiple constraints" clause requires ALL of the constraints to be true ("And"), it does not mean that ANY of the constraints are true ("Or"). So the correct answer is `NO, there is no way to define a generic constraint that can take several possible numeric types.` It has nothing to do with using Nullable. This is particularly annoying when one wants to create a CLASS(Of T) rather than a method or function -- .Net lacks `Numeric` base type.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, that is what I mean when I write "Your problem is that the default `Nullable` class cannot be used in this way".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I've clarified my answer.